# Fill MultiSelect List with List<String>

Tags: list, flutter, multi-select

As I was not satisfied with my code. I have decided to delete and re-write it. The strange thing is that to check if the data are collected, I am trying to print the result. The result is not displayed properly.
I am getting this error. On one side it is clear, but I do not know how to fix it.

Error: The argument type 'Future<List<MultiSelectItem>>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List<MultiSelectItem>'

Please, can you advise? Many thanks.

```
class Context {
  final int id;
  final String name;
  Context({
    this.id,
    this.name,
  });
}
```

```
MultiSelectBottomSheetField<Context>(
                    key: _multiSelectKeyContext,
                    initialChildSize: 0.7,
                    maxChildSize: 0.95,
                    title: Text("Context",style: TextStyle(fontSize: 19), ),
                    buttonText: Text("Context 66",style: TextStyle(fontSize: 19),),
                    searchTextStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 19),
                    searchHintStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 39),
                    itemsTextStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 19),
                    items: getAllContextInFirebase(),
                    searchable: true,
                    onConfirm: (valueContext) {
                      setState(() {
                        _selectedContext = valueContext;
                      });
                      _multiSelectKeyContext.currentState.validate();
                    },
                    chipDisplay: MultiSelectChipDisplay(
                      onTap: (item) {
                        setState(() {
                          _selectedContext.remove(item);
                        });
                        _multiSelectKeyContext.currentState.validate();
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
```

```
Future<List<MultiSelectItem<Context>>>getAllContextInFirebase () async {

   FirebaseFirestore.instance
       .collection('users')
       .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid)
       .collection('contexts')
       .get()
       .then((QuerySnapshot querySnapshot) {
       querySnapshot.docs.forEach((doc) {
       print ('result query') ;
       print(querySnapshot.docs.first['context_Name']);
       return querySnapshot.docs.first['context_Name'];
     });

   });

//I have also tried the code below:

QuerySnapshot querySnapshot =
   await FirebaseFirestore.instance
       .collection('users')
       .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid)
       .collection("contexts").get();
   for (int i = 0; i < querySnapshot.docs.length; i++) {
     var a = querySnapshot.docs[i];
     print(a.id);
   }
```

Comment: What is the value or structure of  `snap['field_Name'] ?

Comment: it is a string. thank you

Answer (score 0):

The error is obvious in the question which is:

```
type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'MultiSelectItem<Context>'
```

The list `_itemsTest` is a list of type `MultiSelectItem<Context>` and you are trying to add `snap['field_Name']` to it which is `String`, so you have to find a way to convert `snap['field_Name']` to be of type `MultiSelectItem<Context>`

Comment: Thank you. I do not know how to convert a string into a MultiSelectItem<Context>. Please, can you advise? Many thanks

Comment: Convert it to `Context` widget and give it an `id` and then convert the context into `MultiSelectItem<Context>` by the following MultiSelectItem<Context>(context, context.name)

Comment: Thank you. Please, is this  correct?

for (int i=0;i<snapshot.data.docs.length;i++){
                              DocumentSnapshot snap = snapshot.data.docs[i];
                              _All_Contexts_In_FireBase.add(snap['context_Name']);
                            }

                            final test = _All_Contexts_In_FireBase.map((e) => Context);
                            
                            final children = test
                                .map((context) => MultiSelectItem<Context>(context, context.name))
                                .toList();